# Swift. When should you define an Object / Value with specific data type

Tags: swift

As I started developing with Swift and searching through different tutorials and documentations about the language, I'm not sure about one thing.
You can declare an object / value with a specific data type like this:

```
var aString:String = "Test"
var anObject:SKScene = ASceneClass()
```

Or you can just do it like this:

```
var aString = "Test"
var anObject = ASceneClass()
```

The result will be exactly the same (ASceneClass inherits from SKScene of course)

As everyone is doing it different I wonder if there's a logical reason behind it or you do it for readability ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring type right after variable name is called **Type Annotation**

When you don't do that, you have to provide initial value

```
var aString = "Test"
```

Often value is not known at that moment, or you are not even sure if it's going to be not nil value, then you can declare it as optional

```
var aString:String?
```

If you would like to declare variable without any initiaization but you are sure it's not going to evaluate to nil, you force unwrap it

```
var aString:String!
```

This is the definition. In practice, it's always better to use type annotations even when you initialize variable with value, because later in your program you will notice anytime you mess something with the type of the variable.

Also, When you declare an array or dictionary, usually nested ones, Xcode might expect them to have type annotations since it might have some issues with writing values when the type is not known in advance.

**To recap**

You will want to use type annotations whenever you can, which means whenever you are sure about the variable's type in advance

Answer (score 1):

Recommended/Documented way to declare a variable in swift is as follow:

```
var <variable name>: <type> = <initial value/expression>
```

> **Note:** Given form declares a stored variable or stored variable property. Its used when you are clear about `type annotation` of it.

Though its valid to declare variable without its Type.

```
var variableName = <initial value>
```

> **Note:** When you don't know `type annotation` its mandatory to assign 'Initial value' to that variable.

Refer Swift Documentation on [Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) for more details.